# Quarkus docker run exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: quarkus

i'm following the quarkus getting-started tutorials, was able to generate executable and ran it but cannot get the docker image run.

Steps:

1. ./mvnw package -Pnative (it worked)
2. docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t quarkus/getting-started . (it worked
3. docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkus/getting-started, got this error:

   standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

my settings:
Quarkus version: 2.7.2.final
macOS Catalina version 10.15.7
Java version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.0.0.2 (build 11.0.14+9-jvmci-22.0-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.0.0.2 (build 11.0.14+9-jvmci-22.0-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
```

maven version: 3.8.3

please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you build your native executable on Mac and then push it to a Linux based container. You could use

```
./mvnw package -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

to instruct Quarks to build a native Linux executable using a container runtime (Docker in your case).

https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#container-runtime